# Using Holder's inequality to prove interpolation property in $l^p$ sequence spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I wish to prove that if $x \in l^q \cap l^q$ with $1 \leq q < r$ then for any $p$ with $q < p < r$ we have $||x||_{l^p} \leq ||x||_{l^q}^{q(r-p)/p(r-q)} ||x||_{l^r}^{r(p-q)/p(r-q)}$ using Holder's Inequality, which states that:

If $1\leq p,q \leq \infty$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$ then $\sum_{k=0}^\infty |x_ky_k| \leq ||x||_{l^p}||x||_{l^q}$.

So far, I have shown that $x \in l^p$ and noted that $q(r-p)/p(r-q) + r(p-q)/p(r-q) = 1$, so tried to use Holder's Theorem with $p(r-q)/q(r-p)$ and $p(r-q)/r(p-q)$, but then this gives the wrong norms.

I'm really unsure as to how to plug this in to Holder's Theorem to give the right exponentials, any advice would be great!

Comment: I think one $q$ in the first line at the $l$s must be a $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You have to choose $a$ and $b$ with $a+b=p$ in such a way that you can apply Holder's inequality in
$$
\|x\|_p^p=\sum |x_i|^p=\sum |x_i|^a|x_i|^b
$$
with exponents $l$ and $m$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{l}+\frac{1}{m}=1
$$
(to be able to use the inequality) and, moreover, $al=q$, $bm=r$ (for the $q$-norm and the $r$-norm to show up). You solve for $a$, $b$, $l$ and $m$ satisfying the four conditions and you get
$$
a=\frac{q(r-p)}{r-q};\quad b=\frac{r(p-q)}{r-q};\quad l=\frac{r-q}{r-p};\quad m=\frac{r-q}{p-q}
$$
You then use Holder's inequality:
$$
\|x\|_p^p=\sum |x_i|^a|x_i|^b\le (\sum |x_i|^q)^{\frac{r-p}{r-q}}(\sum |x_i|^r)^{\frac{p-q}{r-q}}=\|x\|_q^{\frac{q(r-p)}{r-q}} \|x\|_r^{\frac{r(p-q)}{r-q}}
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

There is this following version of Hölder's inequality:

Take $p \in (q,r)$ and consider $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{\vartheta}{q} + \frac{1-\vartheta}{r}$ where $\vartheta \in (0,1)$. Then you have
$$
\|f\|_p \leq \|f\|_r^{1-\vartheta} \|f\|_q^{\vartheta}.
$$

The proof goes a bit likes this: First set $\vartheta := \frac{r-p}{r-q} \in (0,1)$ from which we get $p = \vartheta q + (1-\vartheta)r$. Using this we get
$$
\|f\|^p_p = \||f|^p\|_1 = \| |f|^{\vartheta q} |f|^{(1-\vartheta)r}\|_1 \leq \||f|^{\vartheta q}\|_{\frac{1}{\vartheta}} \| \||f|^{(1-\vartheta)r}\|_{\frac{1}{1-\vartheta}} = 
\|f\|_{q}^{q\vartheta} \| \|f\|_{r}^{r(1-\vartheta)},
$$
where the inequality is a use of Hoelder. Now, devide by $p$ and arrive at
$$
\|f\|^p \leq 
\|f\|_{q}^{\frac{q}{p}\vartheta} \| \|f\|_{r}^{\frac{r}{p}(1-\vartheta)}.
$$
To get to your result, just notice that by setting $\vartheta := \frac{r-p}{r-q} \in (0,1)$ you get your result.